# Hashmap, hashtable, map or anyother method

Tags: arrays, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I am looking to compare two values (like greater than or less than from other) in HashMap, Hashtable, Map or any other Array types.
Could you please help me this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some factors that would affect your selection of a data structure:

- What is the purpose of the comparison?
- What type of data are you comparing?
- How often will data be inserted into this data structure?
- How often will data be selected from this data structure?

**When should you use a HashMap?**

> One should use HashMap when their major requirements are only retrieving or modifying data's based on Key. For example, in Web
>   Applications username is stored as a key and user data is stored as a
>   value in the HashMap, for faster retrieval of user data corresponding
>   to a username.

[HashMap](https://www.quora.com/When-should-we-use-HashMap-over-ArrayList)

**When should you use a HashTable?**

> The input can't be hashed (e.g. you're given binary blobs and don't know which bits in there are significant, but you do have an int cmp(const T&, const T&) function you could use for a std::map), or
>
> the available/possible hash functions are very collision prone, or
>
> you want to avoid worst-case performance hits for:
>
> handling lots of hash-colliding elements (perhaps "engineered" by
>   someone trying to crash or slow down your software)
>
> resizing the hash table: unless presized to be large enough (which can
>   be wasteful and slow when excessive memory's used), the majority of
>   implementations will outgrow the arrays they're using for the hash
>   table every now and then, then allocate a bigger array and copy
>   content across: this can make the specific insertions that cause this
>   rehashing to be much slower than the normal O(1) behaviour, even
>   though the average is still O(1); if you need more consistent
>   behaviour in all cases, something like a balance binary tree may serve
>
> your access patterns are quite specialised (e.g. frequently operating
>   on elements with keys that are "nearby" in some specific sort order),
>   such that cache efficiency is better for other storage models that
>   keep them nearby in memory (e.g. bucket sorted elements), even if
>   you're not exactly relying on the sort order for e.g. iteration

[HashTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189665/when-to-use-hash-tables)